# How to use Deep Neural Networks for regression?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, deep-learning, regression

I wrote this script (Matlab) for classification using Softmax. Now I want to use same script for regression by replacing the **Softmax** output layer with a Sigmoid or ReLU activation function. But I wasn't able to do that.

```
X=houseInputs ;
T=houseTargets;
%Train an autoencoder with a hidden layer of size 10 and a linear transfer function for the decoder. Set the L2 weight regularizer to 0.001, sparsity regularizer to 4 and sparsity proportion to 0.05.

hiddenSize = 10;
autoenc1 = trainAutoencoder(X,hiddenSize,...
    'L2WeightRegularization',0.001,...
    'SparsityRegularization',4,...
    'SparsityProportion',0.05,...
    'DecoderTransferFunction','purelin');
%% 
%Extract the features in the hidden layer.

features1 = encode(autoenc1,X);
%Train a second autoencoder using the features from the first autoencoder. Do not scale the data.

hiddenSize = 10;
autoenc2 = trainAutoencoder(features1,hiddenSize,...
    'L2WeightRegularization',0.001,...
    'SparsityRegularization',4,...
    'SparsityProportion',0.05,...
    'DecoderTransferFunction','purelin',...
    'ScaleData',false);

features2 = encode(autoenc2,features1);

%% 
softnet = trainSoftmaxLayer(features2,T,'LossFunction','crossentropy');
%Stack the encoders and the softmax layer to form a deep network.

deepnet = stack(autoenc1,autoenc2,softnet);
%Train the deep network on the wine data.

deepnet = train(deepnet,X,T);
%Estimate the deep network, deepnet.

y = deepnet(X);
```

Answer (score 1):

Regression is a different problem from classification. You have to change your loss function to something that fits with a regression e.g. mean square error and of course change the number of neuron to one (you will only ouput 1 value on your last layer).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use a Neural Network to perform a regression task but it might be an overkill for many tasks. True regression means to perform a mapping of one set of continuous inputs to another set of continuous outputs:

```
f: x -> ý
```

Changing the architecture of a neural network to make it perform a regression task is usually fairly simple. Instead of mapping the continuous input data to a specific class as it is done using the Softmax function as in your case, you have to make the network use only a single output node.

This node will just sum the outputs of the the previous layer (last hidden layer) and multiply the summed activations by **1**. During the training process this output **ý** will be compared to the correct ground-truth value **y** that comes with your dataset. As a loss function you may use the [Root-means-squared-error (RMSE)](https://www.kaggle.com/wiki/RootMeanSquaredError).

Training such a network will result in a model that maps an arbitrary number of independent variables **x** to a dependent variable **ý**, which basically is a regression task.

To come back to your Matlab implementation, it would be incorrect to change the current Softmax output layer to be an activation function such as a Sigmoid or ReLU. Instead your would have to implement a custom **RMSE** output layer for your network, which is fed with the sum of activations coming from the last hidden layer of your network.

Comment: excellent explanation.So in attached script what should be the training function instead softmax?                                                                  
`softnet = trainSoftmaxLayer(features2,T,'LossFunction','crossentropy');`